# Import Static for Classes in another Package

Tags: java, import, package

How can I import Classes from another packages as static

```
import Package.class;
```

works perfectly fine, but

```
import static Package.class;
```

gives me a java.lang.error compilation Exception

Is it possible or do I just have to put up with it ?

Comment: Please refer to [java import static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to have a better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the static members of the class, not the class itself:

```
import static somePackage.SomeClass.*; // imports all static members
```

or list the desired members individually:

```
import static somePackage.SomeClass.staticField1;
import static somePackage.SomeClass.staticField2;
import static somePackage.SomeClass.staticMethod1;
// etc.
```

P.S. There's no such thing in Java as a "static package".

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of `static` keyword in import statement is not to import class; rather it is intended to import static members (viz. methods, public variables) of class

try something like below and it will work perfectly fine.

`import static java.lang.Math.PI;` and / or `import static java.lang.Math.random;`